# Как мне решить проблему с выходом блока за экран?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я сделал кнопку, при нажатии на которую разворачивается меню. По мере уменьшения экрана блок header__menu уходит за пределы сайта. Умоляю, помогите мне пожалуйста я вообще тупой делал 6 часов и пытаюсь решить эту проблему 2часа

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const btnMenu = document.querySelector(".header__btn-menu");
  const Menu = document.querySelector(".header__menu");
  btnMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
    btnMenu.classList.toggle("header__btn-menu_active");
  });
  btnMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Menu.classList.toggle("header__menu_active");
  });
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 433px) {
  .header__logo {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex: 1 0;
  }
  .header__button {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .header__menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    //left: 150px;
    gap: 0 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    //width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-right: 60px; //40
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #11111129;
    transform-origin: right center;
    transform: translateX(119%); //119%
    //transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.4s;
    &_active {
      transform: translateX(140px);
      padding-left: 20px;
      //transform: scaleX(1);
    }
  }
  .header__btn-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 3px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 17px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #000000;
      &::before,
      &::after {
        content: "";
        transition: all 0.4s;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 2px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #000000;
      }
      &::before {
        transform: translateY(-4px);
        transform-origin: left bottom;
        //left: -3px;
      }
      &::after {
        transform: translateY(4px);
        transform-origin: left top;
        //left: -3px;
      }
    }
    &_active {
      span {
        border-radius: 0;
        //left: 0px;
        &::before {
          transform: rotate(35deg);
          width: 10px;
          border-radius: 0;
        }
        &::after {
          transform: rotate(-35deg);
          width: 10px;
          border-radius: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__logo">
      <div class="header__img"><img src="./assets/images/Logo.png" alt="#"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="header__menu menu">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">FEATURES</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">SUPPORT</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="header__button">
      <a class="button-blue" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
    </div>
    <button class="header__btn-menu"><span></span></button>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `//width: 250px;` для начала почитайте как закоментаривать строки в css.  ну, а по делу - откройте в браузере инструменты разработчика (например в FireFox - по мне так у них они самые удобные) и исследуйте ширину вашего  блока и его поведение по мере уменьшения размеров окна браузера и увидите, какой код в `css` не дает ему вести себя так как нужно.